# I can't connect to the server via Retrofit

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit

Can't connect to local server via android. The server is working correctly (checked through the console + checked through the console on the phone).
on the server, the port is specified as 3000
local server device id 192.168.0.107

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        ApiInterface.create()
    }
}
```

```
interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("volley_array.json")
    fun getMovies() : List<String>

    companion object {
        private const val BASE_URL = "https://192.168.0.107:3000"

        fun create() : ApiInterface {
            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .build()
            return retrofit.create(ApiInterface::class.java)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add / to end of the base url.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the devices are connected on the same modem or router.

Example:
Server IP: 192.168.0.107
Device IP: 192.168.0.56

If you are using port 3000, you must open it in the modem or router with reference to your server or application.

Answer (score 0):

You can try via `ngrok` (https://ngrok.com/download) Add this `/` end of base url:

```
ngrok http 3000
```